# Chicago Fig tree care

Tags: trees

My daughter bought me two Chicago Fig trees and I had no idea what to do with them.  They need no help in south Alabama, but south east Nebraska is a different story.  They are temporary in shipping pots, but if I have to bring them in in the winter, I have to put in larger pots right away.  Thank you for any help I can get.

Comment: What are the lowest temperatures you get .  Do you have a sheltered spot outside

Comment: Chicago is a lot further north than Alabama, and Nebraska so I don't see how there would be a temperature problem.

Comment: Are you being funny black thumb?  LOL.

Comment: @41DollieD You need to plan for winters.  Large pots are easily moved by using simple Dollies!  I am so bad.  Simply a rack with wheels that rotate.  Where you live plants in pots will not make it through a winter no matter the size of the pot.  Roots are fragile and susceptible to too cold and too hot of temperatures.  In pots their roots are exposed to temperatures that wouldn't be a problem in the large body of garden soil.  There are options using strings of xmas tree lights, not LEDs and wrapping the entire plant with burlap.  Major headache and always a risk.  Especially in Chicago.